# Can the word "derive" be used to mean "take the derivative of"?

Tags: calculus, soft-question, terminology

Back when I was in high school, the usage of the word "derive" to mean "take the derivative of" was really widespread. It always bothered me because I felt that the proper verb should be "differentiate." I wondering if this use of "derive" is acceptable or not. Has anyone else heard the word "derive" used in this way?

Comment: Not from mathematicians. If I heard someone say "derive" in this sense I would understand what they meant, but assume they were a non-native speaker or a beginning student.

Comment: I tend to hear it from non-native speakers of English (along with things such as "derivate"); of course, I very much prefer "differentiate", even if it's longer...

Comment: But "derived function" is the result of this "differentiation".   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-Hqdyd97Qg&hd=1

Comment: Without this use of "derive" we wouldn't be able to say the joke "Don't drink and derive".  "Don't drink and take derivatives" just doesn't work.

Comment: I heard it for the very first time on MSE itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I say "not acceptable".

I don't recall the grammatical/linguistic term, but it seems like "derive" in that sense needs a "from" somewhere: "This theorem can be derived from blah blah."

"Differentiate", on the other hand, can be used directly with its object: "let's differentiate $f$" and so on.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_verb

Comment: So "derive" is intransitive? But intransitive verbs don't take an object, and it seems strange to say "This function can be derived", where there's no object. Can we crosslist this question with english.stackexchange? :)

Comment: What about the derived group?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an [illuminating xkcd forum thread](http://forums.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=34442) on the topic. People (myself included) seem to agree that the word 'derive' is incorrect.

Comment: Link is dead...