# How do you derive the formula of $\sin (a+b)$ from $\cos(a+b)=\cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b)$

Tags: trigonometry

I know that cos is even while sin is odd, and I know $\cos(\pi)=\sin((\pi/2)-x)$, but I  still can't figure the derivation of $\sin (a+b)$ from $\cos(a+b)=\cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b)$. Could you give me any hint?

Comment: This can be proven easily from Euler's Formula. $e^{i \theta} = cos(\theta) + isin(\theta)$

Comment: Does it really *derive* the formula for sine from the formula for cosine?

Comment: @Bernard You could frame it that way, but I suppose it's sort of a cheat to do so. You could start by defining sin, cos and e^x all in terms of the taylor series. He's probably looking for a more elementary proof, but this one deserves to be mentioned because its so simple.

Answer (score 6):

$$\sin(a+b)=\cos\left(\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-a\right)+(-b)\right)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-a\right)\cos(-b)-\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-a\right)\sin(-b)\\=\sin(a)\cos(-b)-\cos(a)(-\sin(b))=\sin(a)\cos(b)+\cos(a)\sin(b)$$

Answer (score 4):

**A very short hint:**

Deriving ;o)

*and some details:*

Start from
$$\cos(a+b)=\cos a \cos b-\sin a\sin b$$
and differentiate w. r. t., say, $a$:
$$-\sin(a+b)=-\sin a\cos b-\cos a \sin b.$$

Comment: Is it so elliptic?

Comment: What is  ;o) supposed to mean?

Comment: Bernard was just noting the humor that the OP was using "derive" in the colloquial sense of "figure out," but that coincidentally "take the derivative of" is a good way to do so.

Comment: @Simpson17866 That's not the colloquial way of using derive, that is the "official way". As a matter of fact, using "derive" to mean "differentiate" isn't quite right. Either way I don't think this answer is useful, -1

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80517/can-the-word-derive-be-used-to-mean-take-the-derivative-of

Comment: Sure, that piece of technical information was good to know and I'm surprised that I'd missed it for this long, but does the fact that a pun is not "technically" correct mean that the pun is "wrong"? If I said "I used to be a banker, but I lost interest," would the play on the word "interest" be a point in favor of the pun or a point against?

Comment: In my opinion, it'd be a point in favour of the pun…

Comment: I don't want to discuss puns. I'm just saying that I as a person with a degree in mathematics couldn't make sense of a cryptic word and three symbols. A person that is struggling with trig is less likely than me to understand and the original answer should have been a comment at best. Since details have been filled in I changed the -1 to +1.

Comment: @avid19: Hints, in my mind, are written to make people *think*, not to give the answers. And my education – certainly very old style – taught me that sometimes, to say more, you have to say less. The most striking example I can give is a sentence by the Latin writer Suetonius which was the starting point of the classical French tragedy *Bérénice* (the story of the Roman emperor Titus and the Jewish princess Berenice), which is all contained in this very short sentence: *Invitus invitam dimisit* ([He] sent her back against his will, against her will).

Comment: I have no issues with hints. I use them too. However I think hints should be decipherable. A single, incorrectly used word does not fall under that umbrella. However your answer is totally okay to me now so the conversation is irrelevant. :)

Comment: @avid The three cryptic sumbols are called a [smiley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smiley). I don't know what's Bernard mother tongue, but at least in french, "differentiate" is said "dériver", hence a possible translation mistake (see the first comment of the question you refer to). Since differentiating yields the [derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative), even if wrong, it should be understandable (at least to me it was, but maybe I'm biased, since I'm french).

Comment: @avid By the way, I don't think MSE users can be expected to write a perfect english. This is the most widespread language on earth. The downside is, it's also the most victim of bad usage.

Answer (score 4):

Since Element118 has already given what you expected, here is a geometric proof (the grey squares represent right angle).

[image: trig_form]

By definition, we know that $$\sin(\alpha+\beta)=\frac{|BC|+|CD|}{|AB|}=\frac{|BC|}{|AB|}+\frac{|CD|}{|AB|}$$

We want $$\cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta)+\cos(\beta)\sin(\alpha)$$

We have $\cos(\alpha)=\frac{|BC|}{|BE|}$ and $\sin(\beta)=\frac{|BE|}{|AB|}$ 
and it gives:
\begin{equation*}
\frac{|BC|}{|AB|}=\frac{|BC|\cdot|BE|}{|AB|\cdot|BE|}=\underbrace{\frac{|BC|}{|BE|}}_{\cos(\alpha)}\underbrace{\frac{|BE|}{|AB|}}_{\sin(\beta)}
\end{equation*}
We repeat this for $\frac{|CD|}{|AB|}$ and we get

\begin{equation}
\sin(\alpha+\beta)=\cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta)+\cos(\beta)\sin(\alpha)
\end{equation}

Comment: See also [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1342/409).

Comment: @Blue Very interesting! Thanks.